# I am trying to push the file using adb to my android device

Tags: android, hosts

I am trying to push the edited host file to android device by using the command `adb push /root/android_hosts/hosts`

Here I am getting the error message something like this,

```
system/etcfailed to copy '/root/android_hosts/hosts' to 'system/etc/hosts': Permission denied
```

Comment: SuperUser is not about mobile devices. See help->Help Center to see what questions are allowed here on SuperUser.

Comment: @LPChip "except insofar as they interface with your computer". `adb` is the Android debugger that runs on the PC and can be used, amongst other things, to push files to an Android device. While this *might* get a better answer on [Android.se] it *is* on topic here.

Comment: @Mokubai oh my bad. I don't have any android experience and thus I didn't linked this as being insofar. Thanks for the headsup.

Comment: What is that `.` doing straight after hosts, and maybe you should try the adb push command with two parameters  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20834241/how-to-use-adb-command-to-push-a-file-on-device-without-sd-card  And your title makes no sense. You are not trying to push adb, you are using adb to push a file

Comment: @barlop Acccidently put the dot in my question

Comment: @SachinVaidya and how it is meant to know what file you are trying to push?  you've only specified the destination on the device. Also try `adb shell` and see if you can browse to that location of the device

Comment: There are three things to consider: 1) Use `adb shell <SOURCE> <DESTINATION>` to avoid confusing readers, 2) you've not mentioned whether your `/system` is mounted as RW or not. Normally, it is always RO so a error is going to show (the error would be: read-only file system).  3) If you've `/system` mounted as RW, do you have root privileges (is ADB running as root; or kernel running in insecure mode)?

Answer (score 1):

You can't push a file to /system because you dont have at-time permission and the /system is not mounted yet.

Move the file to the sdcard first,

```
adb push /root/android_hosts/hosts /mnt/sdcard/hosts
```

Then enter in adb shell and mount /system as root

```
adb shell
su
mount -o remount,rw /system
```

So, just copy the file to /system/etc/

```
cp -fp /mnt/sdcard/hosts /system/etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 0):

i used this and you cant transfer folders and when pushing file you must put the type of file like .bat or .mp3
Like so

```
adb push C:\Windows\folder\loldkd.mp4 /sdcard/
```